# What's the point of activating extension with * and other events at the same time in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I see people using `*` (startup event) combined with other events:

```js
"activationEvents": [
    "*",
    "onCommand:extension.toggleCase"
],
```

Why?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager/pull/97

Comment: You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, adding an explicit `onCommand` activation event can help to avoid "command not found" errors when running a command while VSCode is still in the process of starting extensions. Some relevant links:

- https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager/pull/97
- https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager/issues/96